# Acumatica REST API - adding shipment generates error

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am going through the I330 training. I had no issues with I310, and I320 - everything worked in those courses. I am working against the DEMO install.

When I issue a PUT to the endpoint I get a `PX.Data.PXInvalidOperationException`
I have the following query vars set: `$expand Details` `$select Type,ShipmentNbr,Status,FreightCurrencyID,Details/InventoryID`

And, the following in the body:

```
{
   "Type":{"value":"Shipment"},
   "CustomerID":{"value":"RETSALE"},
   "WarehouseID":{"value":"RETAIL"},
   "ShipmentDate":{"value":"2023-02-24"},
   "FreightCurrencyID":{"value":"USD"},
   "Details":[
     {
       "OrderType":{"value":"SO"},
       "OrderNbr":{"value":"000029"}
     }
    ]
}
```

`FreightCurrencyID` is not in the instructions. However, without it I was getting and error - `CurryID cannot be empty`

Here is the stacktrace:

```
 at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Put(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean throwOnError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.PutImpl(EntityImpl entity, Boolean throwOnValidationError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.PutEntity(EntityImpl entity, String select, String filter, String expand, String custom)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.",
        "exceptionType": "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException",
        "stackTrace": "   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass90_1.<FindImplementations>b__3(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.ProcessLocateByNoteIdCommand(SyCommand cmd, SyView view, Boolean invokeCommand)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.ProcessCommand(SyCommand cmd, Boolean& needCommit)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()",
        "innerException": {
            "message": "An error has occurred.",
            "exceptionMessage": "Currency Rate is not defined.",
            "exceptionType": "PX.Objects.CM.PXRateNotFoundException",
            "stackTrace": "   at                                                                   
            PX.Objects.CM.PXCurrencyAttribute.PXCurrencyHelper.CuryConvCury(CurrencyInfo info, Decimal baseval, Decimal& curyval, Int32 precision)\r\n 
  at PX.Objects.CM.PXCurrencyAttribute.PXCurrencyHelper.CuryConvCury(CurrencyInfo info, Decimal baseval, Decimal& curyval, Boolean skipRounding)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.CM.PXCurrencyAttribute.PXCurrencyHelper.CuryConvCury[CuryField](PXCache sender, Object row)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.SO.FreightCalculator.CalcFreightCost[T,CuryFreightCostField](PXCache sender, T data)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.RecalculateFreight(SOShipment row, SOShipment oldRow)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.SOShipment_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)\r\n   
  at PX.Data.PXRowUpdated.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)\r\n  
  at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowUpdated(Object newItem, Object oldItem, Boolean externalCall)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXFormulaAttribute.UpdateParent(PXCache sender, Object row, Object oldrow, Func`3 ensureNewParentFunc)\r\n    
  at PX.Data.PXFormulaAttribute.RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)\r\n 
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowUpdated(Object newItem, Object oldItem, Boolean externalCall)\r\n
   at PX.Objects.IN.GraphExtensions.LineSplittingExtension`4.UpdateParent(TSplit newSplit, TSplit oldSplit)\r\n
   at PX.Objects.IN.GraphExtensions.LineSplittingExtension`4.EventHandler(Args e)\r\n   
   at PX.Objects.SO.GraphExtensions.SOShipmentEntryExt.SOShipmentLineSplittingExtension.EventHandler(Args e)\r\n   
  at PX.Data.PXRowInserted.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)\r\n   
  at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowInserted(Object item, Object pending, Boolean externalCall)\r\n    
  at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)\r\n   
  at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.InsertSplitsForNonLotsOnLocation(SOShipLine newline, INLotSerClass lotserclass, Nullable`1 locationID, Nullable`1 availableQty, Nullable`1 plannedQty)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.CreateSplitsForAvailableNonLotsImpl[L,LA,S,SA](Nullable`1 PlannedQty, String origPlanType, SOShipLine newline, INLotSerClass lotserclass)\r\n  
   at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.CreateSplitsForAvailableNonLots(Nullable`1 PlannedQty, String origPlanType, SOShipLine newline, INLotSerClass lotserclass)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.ShipAvailableNonLots(SOShipmentPlan plan, SOShipLine newline, INLotSerClass lotserclass)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.ShipAvailable(SOShipmentPlan plan, SOShipLine newline, PXResult`2 item)\r\n   
  at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.CreateShipmentFromSchedules(PXResult`7 res, SOShipLine newline, SOOrderType ordertype, String operation, DocumentList`1 list)\r\n
   at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.CreateShipment(CreateShipmentArgs args)\r\n
   at PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.AddSO(PXAdapter adapter)\r\n
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.RunHandler(PXAdapter adapter)\r\n 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__38.MoveNext()\r\n 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__38.MoveNext()\r\n
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.PressImpl(Boolean internalCall, Boolean externalCall)\r\n
   at PX.Objects.DefaultEndpointImpl.ShipmentDetail_Insert(PXGraph graph, EntityImpl entity, EntityImpl targetEntity)"
```

I saw "currency rate is not defined" and tried adding a decimal value. But, that had no effect. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: On screen, if you manually create a shipment for RETSALE. Is there a default currency ? Normally you don't need to assign this in the API as there should be a default as per Customer's.

Comment: @Rick Interestingly, I get the same error when I try to create a shipment on screen. Currency is set in the top customer info area on the SO screen